# How to get the amount of characters in a label (VB)

Tags: vb.net, label

I've looked everywhere, but I can't find how to do this in VB

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text of a label is a **String**. Strings have a [Length property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx), which returns the number of characters in the string. Thus, the following should work:

```
numberOfCharacters = myLabel.Text.Length
```